# D6 Views exposed filter on Search Term field that handles word parts

Tags: views, search, input-formats

Is there anyway to have a View with an exposed Search Term field return results for word parts?  I am currently using Drupal search.  I'd like to use a hook inside of a custom module rather then going the Apache SOLR route.  Can this be done?